# Allocating more Video RAM to wine

Tags: macos, wine

I'm using wine on my mac to play Universe Sandbox 2. When I open the game, it warns me that I at least need 512MB of VRAM, when I currently have 64MB. I have a Macbook Pro Retina (Mid-2014), and I think I have about 1.5GB of VRAM. Is there anyway to make wine allocate more VRAM?

Comment: AskUbuntu's [How to increase video memory in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517039/how-to-increase-video-memory-in-wine-wine-version-1-6-2) answers suggests using `winetricks videomemorysize=1024` or however many megabytes you want to set.

Answer (score 3):

[You can allow more VRAM by editing the wine registry.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203645/how-to-give-more-ram-to-wine-applications)

1. [Open the wine registry editor by invoking the command `wine regedit` in Terminal.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKyZWHKHLb4)
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER → Software → Wine → Direct3D → VideoMemorySize` and set the value as appropriate.
   If you see no such key, create it (right-click on *Direct3D*, select *New* then *String Value* and name it VideoMemorySize).

More registry information:  [useful registry keys](http://wiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys) from wiki.winehq.org.

This [detailed memory management](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/x2800) page from the wine developer notes might give more clues but it is quite technical.